# Error in running power shell with Get-SPWeb for SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, bulk

I am to run following script on SharePoint Online Management Shell, to bulk upload documents with metadata, but getting error(below screen shots)

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
#Configuration Variables
$SiteURL="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/CMS/"
$LibraryName="TestLibrary"
$FilesPath="C:\Users\userX\Desktop\Upload Test 4 sug\NaUpload"
$CSVFilePath="C:\Users\userX\Desktop\Upload Test 4 sug\Nature.csv"

#Get the Web
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb $SiteURL
#Get the Target Document Library to upload
$Library = $Web.GetFolder($LibraryName)

#Get CSV file contents
$CSVData = Import-CSV -path $CSVFilePath

#Iterate through each Row in the CSV
Foreach ($Row in $CSVData)
{
    write-host "Uploading File:"$Row.FileName

    #Get the File from local disk 
    $SourcePath= Join-Path $FilesPath -ChildPath $Row.FileName
    $SourceFile = (Get-ChildItem $SourcePath).OpenRead()

    #Set Metadata Hashtable For the file
    $Metadata = @{"Document No" = $Row.Document_x0020_No; "Title" = $Row.Title}

    #upload the file              
    $uploaded = $Library.Files.Add($Row.FileName, $SourceFile, $Metadata, $TRUE)
}
```

**Error:**

[image]

---

After, input from @M.Qassas, I made some changes in my script and now I am getting **Null-Valued Expression Error**

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 

#Configuration Variables
$SiteURL= "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/CMS"
$LibraryName= "TestLibrary"
$FilesPath= "C:\Users\userX\Desktop\Upload Test 4 sug\NaUpload"
$CSVFilePath= "C:\Users\userX\Desktop\Upload Test 4 sug\Nature.csv"

#Get the SpoWeb
$Web = Get-SPOSite $SiteURL
#Get the Target Document Library to upload
$Library = $Web.web.list.GetByTitle($LibraryName)

#Get CSV file contents
$CSVData = Import-CSV -path $CSVFilePath

#Iterate through each Row in the CSV
Foreach ($Row in $CSVData)
{
    write-host "Uploading File:"$Row.Name

    #Get the File from local disk 
    $SourcePath= Join-Path $FilesPath -ChildPath $Row.Name
    $SourceFile = (Get-ChildItem $SourcePath).OpenRead()

    #Set Metadata Hashtable For the file
    $Metadata = @{"Document No" = $Row.Document_x0020_No; "Title" = $Row.Title}

    #upload the file              
    $uploaded = $Library.Files.Add($Row.Name, $SourceFile, $Metadata, $TRUE)
}
```

**Error:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**For the first error,** in SharePoint online there is no direct command to `Get-SPWeb` , you should use `SharePoint Client Side model` as shown below:

```
function Get-SPOWebs($url){

#fill metadata information to the client context variable

$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url)

$context.Credentials = $SPOcredentials

$web = $context.Web

$context.Load($web)

$context.Load($web.Webs)

$context.load($web.lists)

try{

$context.ExecuteQuery()

#loop through all lists in the web

foreach($list in $web.lists){

add-content -value "<tr><td><span style='margin-left:$($pixelslist)px'>$($list.title)</td><td>List/library</td><td></td><td>$($list.itemcount)</td></tr>" -path $filePath

}

#loop through all webs in the web and start again to find more subwebs

$pixelsweb = $pixelsweb + 15

$pixelslist = $pixelslist + 15

foreach($web in $web.Webs) {

add-content -value "<tr style='background-color:yellow'><td><span style='margin-left:$($pixelsweb)px'>$($web.url)</td><td>Web</td><td>$($web.webtemplate)</td><td></td></tr>" -path $filePath

write-host "Info: Found $($web.url)" -foregroundcolor green

Get-SPOWebs($web.url)

}

}

catch{

write-host "Could not find web" -foregroundcolor red

}
```

For more details check

- [get site, web and list information with PowerShell for SharePoint Online](http://www.sharepointfire.com/2016/01/get-site-web-and-list-information-with-powershell-for-sharepoint-online/)
- [SharePoint Online and PowerShell: How to Get-Spweb?](http://sharing-the-experience.blogspot.com/2013/10/sharepoint-online-and-powershell-how-to.html)

**For the second error,** based on your script, `$Web` does not exist and not set before, So make sure it's `$spWeb`

---

**Note:** try to setup and run your script using [SharePoint Online Management Shell](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-up-the-SharePoint-Online-Management-Shell-environment-7b931221-63e2-45cc-9ebc-30e042f17e2c)

Comment: 'PS C:\Windows> $Web = Get-SPOWeb $SiteURL'                                                                                                
**Get-SPOWeb : The term 'Get-SPOWeb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:8
+ $Web = Get-SPOWeb $SiteURL
+        ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-SPOWeb:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException**

Comment: getting above, when running with Get-SPOWeb

Comment: Try to Set up the SharePoint Online Management Shell environment https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-up-the-SharePoint-Online-Management-Shell-environment-7b931221-63e2-45cc-9ebc-30e042f17e2c

Comment: Tried but same result...

Answer (score 2):

First you need to refer SharePoint client dlls

```
Add-Type -Path "\\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

#next pass the credentials and connect to web    
$siteURL = ""     
$userName = ""   
$PlainPassword = ""  
$password = $PlainPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

# set SharePoint Online credentials
$SPOCredentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userName, $password)  

#Creating client context object
$clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteURL)
$clientContext.credentials = $SPOCredentials  

$web = $clientContext.Web  
$clientContext.load($web)  
$clientContext.executeQuery()
```

Comment: Do I need to add this, before my code !

Comment: your code is in SSOM  , you need to refer dlls to use CSOM, powershell  up to web ,remaining need to change to csom

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I do not have any coding background.  Made some changes in my script. Please check my edited question...

Comment: Both `Add-Type` lines throw `Add-Type : Cannot bind parameter 'Path' to the target. Exception setting "Path": "Cannot find path
... because it does not exist."` for me.